# Automating a form: Form error, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘value’ of null

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, keyboard-maestro

I am trying to automate a form but i get an error.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null`

This is the **JS** code.

```
var elemFound = SingleNodeForXPath( searchTitle );
var result = elemFound.value; #### Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null ###
return "GOOD:" + result;
})();
```

This is the end of the js code and error.

This is the **HTML** code.

```
<input class="form-control decimal " id="time_card.monday" name="time_card.monday" 
maxlength="14" value="" onchange="this.value=formatNumber(this.value);onChange('time_card.monday');" style="; " aria-label="Monday">
```

Thanks for all the help in advance.

I am using `keyboard maestro` to automate it :)

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the
`SingleNodeForXPath( searchTitle );` function was unable to find the element you are looking for.

You can try `document.getElementById('time_card.monday')` instead.